# Performing an op:join-inner with op:from-lexicons not working as expected with Optic API

Tags: marklogic, marklogic-10, marklogic-optic-api

I have the following optic query using the `op:from-lexicons` access plan:

```
op:from-lexicons((
        map:map()
            => map:with("lexiconUuid", cts:element-reference(xs:QName("lexiconUuid")))
            => map:with("elementInDocumentToFilter", cts:element-reference(xs:QName("elementInDocumentToFilter")))
            => map:with("documentUuid", cts:element-reference(xs:QName("documentUuid")))
    ),"lexiconView")
    => op:where(op:eq(op:view-col("lexiconView","elementInDocumentToFilter"), "Filter Value"))
    => op:group-by(op:view-col("lexiconView","lexiconUuid"), 
        op:count("countOfDocsMeetingFilter", "documentUuid", map:entry('values', 'distinct'))
    )
    => op:select((
        op:view-col("lexiconView","lexiconUuid"),
        op:as("hasCountOver0", op:gt(op:col("countOfDocsMeetingFilter"), 0))
    ))
```

When I add `op:result()` to this query I get an output like:

| lexiconView.lexiconUuid | hasCountOver0 |
| --- | --- |
| lexicon-uuid-1 | true |
| lexicon-uuid-2 | false |

This query is using the existing indexes to return the `lexiconUuid` and whether or not it appears in any documents based on the filter. When I try to use the query above as the `$rightPlan` for an `op:join-inner` I get no results (as in, no join took place). Here is my query using the lexicon query above:

```
op:from-view("schema", "table1")
    (: table2 contains the lexiconUuid element I want to join the lexicon query with :)
    => op:join-inner(op:from-view("schema", "table2"),
        op:on(
            op:view-col("table1", "someUuid"),
            op:view-col("table2", "someUuid")
        )
    )
    => op:join-inner(
        (: op:from-lexicons() access plan here :),
        op:on(
            op:view-col("table2", "lexiconUuid"),
            op:view-col("lexiconView", "lexiconUuid")
        )
    )
```

I know for a fact that the `lexiconUuid` is present after joining `table2` and exists in the `op:from-lexicons` query (i.e. `lexicon-uuid-1` exists in `table2` so it should join on the "lexiconView" without a problem). I replicated this "lexiconView" as a TDE and the join performs as expected but requires an aggregation on the existing data so I have to `op:group-by()` all of the columns in `table1` and `table2`. I was hoping to be able to use the lexicon to avoid having another TDE and performing a group-by/aggregation on more columns. Is there something I am missing about using the `op:from-lexicons` access plan? Can it be used in joins? Has anyone ran into this before?

Comment: What version of MarkLogic 10 are you using?

Comment: @rjrudin I am currently running MarkLogic 10.0-9.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I heard back from MarkLogic engineers on this and it turns out to be a collation issue. The TDE column is a regular string whereas the lexicon index has a collation in our range index configuration of `http://marklogic.com/collation/`. I was able to fix the issue by adding the collation to my TDE column configuration.

```
<column>
  <name>uuid</name>
  <scalar-type>string</scalar-type>
  <val>uuid</val>
  <collation>http://marklogic.com/collation/</collation>
</column>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any immediate solution ideas, but I know what I would do to try to figure out what's going on.

1. Add some where clauses to narrow the result sets of the queries to a couple of specific records that I expect to match.
2. Print out those result sets. If you post that sample data, then others might be able to replicate.
3. Try replicating with `xdmp:from-literals`

Comment: MarkLogic engineers are currently evaluating this query to determine the root cause of the unexpected results. We will update as soon as we have more information.

Comment: Sounds good. In the mean time I have implemented this using a TDE but I performed the aggregation before joining so I didn't have to account for all of the columns in `table1` and `table2`. Thanks for following up!